# Kadison-Singer problem

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, operator-theory

The Kadison-Singer problem is the following statement:
for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $r\in \mathbb N$ such that
for any bounded operator $A$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$, there exists a partition $(\mathcal P_s)_{1\le s\le r}$ of $\mathbb Z$, with
$$
\max_{1\le s\le r}\Vert P_s(A-\text{diag}A)P_s\Vert_{\mathcal B(\ell^2(\mathbb Z))}\le \epsilon \Vert A-\text{diag}A\Vert_{\mathcal B(\ell^2(\mathbb Z))}\quad\tag {PC}
$$
where $P_s=\sum_{j\in \mathcal P_s} p_j$ and $p_j$ is the orthogonal projection onto
$e_j=(\delta_{j,k})_{k\in \mathbb Z}$; the point is that $r$ depends only on $\epsilon$. This problem is sometimes quoted as the Kadison-Singer conjecture, a rather inaccurate denomination since these authors were inclined to think that the answer should be negative. We have given here the formulation of the Paving Conjecture, known to be equivalent to KS.
Since (PC) seems to be now solved, I will read the paper and I withdraw my question.

Comment: Any reference for that recent result?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I think Bazin is referring to http://www.pnas.org/content/105/14/5313.full although one has to read that paper with a little care, and not just the MR whose 1st version had problems

Comment: BTW, it seems a bit misleading to say KS is open without referring to the recent paper claiming a solution

Comment: If you read french, please consider having a look at:
http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr/TEXTES/1088.pdf

Comment: @AlainValette Merci bien, ca me donne la chance de m'exercer

Answer (score 25):

Virtually everything stated in the question is wrong. The Kadison-Singer problem has been solved positively by Marcus, Spielman, and Srivastava, see:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.3969v3.pdf

The question apparently also refers to an earlier paper of Akemann and me, in which assuming CH we falsified a different conjecture of Kadison and Singer. This problem also has to do with pure states on $B(H)$ so there is some connection with the well-known Kadison-Singer problem.  But it's a different question. See:

http://www.pnas.org/content/105/14/5313.full

Comment: I thought it might be that paper, though I guess we need the OP to confirm this. Confusion may have arisen because the original MathReview of this PNAS paper had an error/mis-statement, which I pointed out to the reviewer, I don't know if the MR has since been revised.

Comment: More precisely, Marcus, Spielman, and Srivastava proved a statement that Nik had previously shown to imply Kadison-Singer.  This is not the end of the story as it remains to get a good dependence of $r$ on $\epsilon$.  AFAIK, Nik's argument does not give anything explicit.

Comment: @Yemon: yes, the original MathReview was a bit embarassing! It was corrected a little while ago.

Comment: @Bill: more precisely, I showed that my statement implied a statement that Akemann and Anderson had previously shown to imply K-S ...

Comment: @Bill: I haven't really thought about it, but doesn't $r$ go like a negative power of $\epsilon$? Do you just want the exponent?

Comment: @Nik Weaver Are you saying that the paving conjecture is solved? I believe that (PC) is stated correctly in my question.

Comment: Yes the paving conjecture is solved.

Comment: Yes, the exponent is important for applications, Nik.  Bourgain-Tzafriri got the best possible one for restricted invertibility.  But do  you even get some exponent from the proof?  To be honest, I have not thought about it, but after looking at the various implications, Schechtman said that he did not see a concrete estimate.

Comment: Bill, the proof of Kadison-Singer works by showing how to pave projection operators. Going from projections to general operators was originally accomplished by Akemann-Anderson using completely nonconstructive infinite-dimensional techniques. Recently Tristan Bice found a more elementary route to this reduction (see his paper "Filters in C*-algebras"), so maybe more information can be extracted there.